# In Webtrends, what is the difference between a HIT, a VISIT and a PAGE VIEW

Tags: webtrends

I cannot seem to find any straight and clear documentation explaining the differences between these value types. Hits used to be any call to the server regardless of the file type, but Webtrends only tracks page views, so how is a page view different for a hit? As for visits, I assume that 1 visit can produce multiple page views.

I am seeking enlightenment.

Xv

UPDATE:

This is a screen cap of the results im trying to understand.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, Hits in this case are equal to page views. 
Hope this helps anyone encountering the same issue with Webtrends.

Answer (score 10):

- Hit - any and every request (image, html, css, js etc...)
- PageView - every request to a page (html, aspx, asp, php etc...)
- Visit - a session, the duration of someone coming to your website, regardless of the number of page views they have generated

These are fairly generic terms and this usage is accepted in most web tracking lingo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Webtrends, but the lingo normally goes something like this:

1. Hit: a request to the web server. While this could be a page, it could also be an image, CSS file, etc.
2. Page view: a request to the web server that is a page.
3. Visit: a unique page view. (unique as in, from the same IP address or same client). Visits depend on what the time frame for unique is; i.e., visits/month is not the same as adding up all of your visits/day.